# Python PySerial - receiving a lot of data

Tags: python, windows, pyserial

I'm using Python 2.7.14, Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit and PySerial 3.4.

I wrote a Python script to connect, download or backup the configuration of a Cisco Switch.

The issue is not getting the entire configuration, if I copy and paste it out of a Putty session and save it in notepad it concludes in 13KB. However when using Serial.InWaiting() I only get 4096 bytes which is a partial configuration.

is there a way to get the entire 13KB of the download using Serial.readall() ?

Thank you,
Dennis.

Comment: `s = ""; while ser.inWaiting() > 0 : s += ser.read(1);`

Comment: I've used the following:
while self.s.inWaiting() > 0:
    self.show_run_v += self.s.read(20)

I didn't use (1) since it exited right away. However, using 20 causes the loop to hang forever, any idea why ?

Comment: If the remaining bytes are not 20, you wait forever. You cannot read as a block if the device is sending you data sequentially. The biggest problem in serial communication is the loss of data index. The length of the incoming data must be divided into 20 full, and all positive integers can be divided into exactly 1(one) number.